# java username and password input validation

Tags: java

I am trying to prompt the user to input his or her username and password when prompted. after they input I am trying to check it against a text file I have stored with my source code.

```
public static void getCreds()
{
    String userName;
    String userPass;

    Scanner credsInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter your username: ");
        userName = credsInput.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter your password: ");
        userPass = credsInput.nextLine();

    boolean found = false;
    String tempUser;
    String tempPass;
    //String fileName = "credentials.txt";

    try
    {
        // Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("credentials.txt")))
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("credentials.txt"));
        scan.useDelimiter(",");

        while (scan.hasNext() && !found)
        {
            tempUser = scan.next();
            tempPass = scan.next();

            if(tempUser.trim().equals(userName.trim()) && tempPass.trim().equals(userPass.trim()))
            {
                found = true;
                System.out.println("success");
            }

        }

        scan.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("invalid");
    }


}
```

and this is the contents of the text file.

```
user1,pass1
bob,1234
jim,1234
```

I don't believe that it is actually reading from the file but I may be wrong, any help is appreciated.

### edit

I forgot to put my output. when I compile and run the code it asks for the username and output successfully and regardless if I put in a correct one or not, it throws the exception and displays

```
invalid
```

### edit #2

my first issue was that I wasn't used to storing text files in java properly. After I changed the text file to the proper place. I was able to change the useDelimiter line successfully

```
scan.useDelimiter(",|\n");
```

now it succesfuly checks both the username and password and outputs

```
Success
```

if the input is in the text file.

Comment: Can you clarify why you don't think it's reading from the file?

Comment: What happened when you execute the program. does it work as you expected?

Comment: Did you use debugger? You will see what file you are using etc...

Comment: You atleast need to provide the output, and share the details how you are debugging your code.

Comment: Make a map out of that .txt file with username being Key and password being Value, after user enters username, loop over keySet of the map and see if that username exists, if it doesn't, let him know, if it does, get the value behind that key and compare it with password, if it's same, login is valid, if not, let him know password is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using hasNextLine() and nextLine() since you know the username and password pairs are on individual lines.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("credentials.txt"));

    while (scan.hasNextLine() && !found)
    {
        String[] userNpwd = scan.nextLine().split(",");
        if(userNpwd.length() == 2)
        {
            tempUser = userNpwd[0];
            tempPass = userNpwd[1];
            if(tempUser.trim().equals(userName.trim()) && tempPass.trim().equals(userPass.trim()))
            {
                found = true;
                System.out.println("success");
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the coma used as a delimeter because it will take for example `1234`appended to the carriage return `\n`as a token , I tried on my IDE like this:

```
   //scan.useDelimiter(",");

        while (scan.hasNext() && !found)
        {
            String line  = scan.nextLine();
            tempUser = line.split(",")[0];
            tempPass = line.split(",")[1];
            //..... complete the logic as it was

          }
         .....
```